# Rotating an image only works on first response

Tags: ios, swift

When I click a button in my app, I want it to rotate 180 degrees. My code below works, however if it click the button again it doesn't rotate at all, it just stays at its original spot.

Here is my code below

```
func animateRecommendButton() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) { () -> Void in
        self.recommendButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of updating the creating new transform update the button's transform**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
   sender.transform = sender.transform.rotated(by:CGFloat.pi)
})
```

[image]

Comment: Answers are more helpful with an explanation of the problem and the solution, instead of a "try this" code dump only.

Comment: Only animates after clicking the button for the first time. After clicking it after the first time, it doesn't animate

Comment: I got it, thanks for showing me the duplicate @rmaddy